# Demandware | Technology stack | Salesforce Commerce Cloud

Tags: e-commerce, demandware

Basically I am a PHP Developer and very soon moving to **Demandware** Platform. I would like to Know what are Languages and technologies which are used in Demandware and like to start learning myself. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to start learning Demandware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769148/i-want-to-start-learning-demandware)

Answer (score 4):

Demandware itself is written in Java but the coding syntax is entirely different.
It basically consists of the following

- ISML files - that are similar to HTML files with additional DW syntaxes
- ds files. These are script files that can perform backend logic
- xml Pipelines - Visual/Functional representation of a logic is given in a Pipeline. ex. Cart-MinicartAdd would add an item to the minicart.
- css,js These are normal css js files that are used like in any other web application

Resources: https://xchange.demandware.com/community/developer
Please note that you need to have a Demandware xchange account to access the tutorials and Api documentation.

Comment: Since early 2016 XML Pipelines are no longer the recommended approach. Demandware introduced CommonJS controller modules to control request & response flow. Additionally the reference app implemented CommonJS model modules and the templates are wrapped by a View model.

Comment: Can you please provide some details on CommonJS model?

Answer (score 3):

See [I want to start learning Demandware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769148/i-want-to-start-learning-demandware/38827191)
Salesforce Commerce Cloud Digital Platform (previously Demandware) is a SaaS ecommerce platform, that uses server-side JavaScript for creating customizations on the site logic.

Comment: Focus on Javascript, CommonJS module syntax, jQuery, NodeJS, npm, and task automators such as Gulp or Grunt. Expect to go to a 4-day introductory class on Developing in Demandware as well as several eLearning courses offered by Demandware.

Answer (score 2):

Several weeks ago I started work with Demandware. So, it's pretty cool platform if you wan't pump your skills with js, css(scss...), html.

Basically, all your back-end - it's work with Demandware API - this is a Model; also you need work with Controllers or Pipelines as a Controllers; your Views - it's a .isml files, something like a HTML + template engine. If you work with .twig before - you will not surprised with .isml

I recommend read this a couple articles and dig some info about Demandware here:

https://blog.baha.dk/2015/09/20/part-1-what-is-demandware/

https://blog.baha.dk/2015/12/20/part-2-developing-demandware/

Unfortunately we have not much sources and knowledge online, college. All info you can find on Demandware XChange community portal and also to the API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Learn somewhat-modern Javascript.  DW/SFCC is based on a hacked up version of server-side Javascript (e.g. NodeJS) w/ some Java references tossed in for fun.  Knowing that and MVC architecture should be sufficient to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this [Demadware MVC Concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111474/demandware-mvc-concept/) question as well for the Demandware MVC concept.

You can have look at the open source documentation [Demadware Documentation](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

Full stack web development knowledge applies here, object oriented programming concepts are needed, then rest is Javascript and you have to interact with the ecosystem API objects to get things done.
Some knowledge of using node tools , npm to install dependencies, compile assets, webpack will help you as its frequently required.
I myself shifted from PHP to SFCC recently.